# ADmob AdRequest is undefined

Tags: android, admob

i have implemented banner ads and it work!
I want implement in MainActivity the Fullscreen Ads

code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Servizi extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.servizi);

      InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
      mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-");

      mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
               @Override
               public void onAdLoaded() {
                   Toast.makeText(Servizi.this,
                           "The interstitial is loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }

               @Override
               public void onAdClosed() {
                   // Proceed to the next level.
                   Toast.makeText(Servizi.this,
                           "The interstitial is CLOSED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

     });
 }
```

}

There aren't error but i can't see this Ads!
My unit ID is correct.
I don't use XML file for this Ad.
Help! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, you are:

1. Never loading an ad.
2. Never asking the ad to be displayed.

Add the following to onCreate

```
// Create ad request.
final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

// Begin loading your interstitial.
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Add a method that displays the interstitial:

```
  // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.
  public void displayInterstitial() {
    if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
      interstitial.show();
    }
  }
```

And call `displayInterstitial` at a natural break point in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you folloed http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup

EDIT:

1. Where do is declaration of Ad.java? Is that some custom class of yours?

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
     if (ad == interstitial) {
       interstitial.show();
     }
   }
   ```
2. AdRequest has private constructor that will prevent you to do following 

   `AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();`
3. To set listener on InterstitialAd you want to do something as bellow

```
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("myAdUnitId");

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
             @Override
             public void onAdLoaded() {
                 Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                         "The interstitial is loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

             @Override
             public void onAdClosed() {
                 // Proceed to the next level.
                 goToNextLevel();
             }
         });
```

Taken from official documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd.html

Comment: I have imported Google play Service. In my app use Google Map API and Google Play Service